# Nginx rewrite "directory" language to query string

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get Nginx to rewrite a fake directory to a query string to be used as the language.  For example:

```
/fr/example.php
```

should look like that in the URL, but should rewrite to

```
/example.php?language=fr
```

Here is the code I have tried in my Nginx config:

```
rewrite "^(/(fr|en))?/(.*).php$" /$3.php?language=$2 last;
```

When I visit `example.php`, I get the correct page, but when I visit `/fr/example.php`, I get a 404 error.

**Edit:** This seems to be somehow related to the fact that it is a `.php` extension.  If I try with .html instead, it works.  But unfortunately I need it to be php.  Here is a little more of my `nginx.conf` that might be helpful, found just a little later than the code I posted above:

```
location / {
    root   /var/www/example.com;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    rewrite "^(/(fr|en))?/(.*).php$" /$3.php?language=$2 last;
}

error_page 404 /404.php;
location /404.php {
    root /var/www/example.com;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    # CUSTOM
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    # END CUSTOM

    # With php7.0-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

Comment: It works for me. Which block is the `rewrite...last` enclosed within?

Comment: It is enclosed with `location / {`, just before the fastcgit block I added.

Comment: That is the problem. It needs to be in a context when `.php` URIs are processed, which means `server` context, or `location ~ \.php$`. If you place it in `location ~ \.php$` - use `rewrite...break` instead.

Comment: I think I don't quite understand: I just tried moving it down into the `location ~ \.php$` block, and my server was showing error 500.  Edit: and my whole posted configuration is within a `server {` block.

Comment: Use `rewrite...break` inside the `location` block.

Comment: Ah, I just had to put it before the snippets!  Thanks a bunch.  If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rewrite` statement needs to be within a context that processes URIs ending with `.php`, which means the `server` block or the `location ~ \.php$` block.

The disadvantage of placing the `rewrite` in the `server` block, is that `nginx` tests the regular expression for every URI rather than only those ending with `.php`.

The `rewrite` statement should use the `break` suffix when the rewritten URI is processed within the same `location` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

For example:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    rewrite ^(/(fr|en))?/(.*)$ /$3?language=$2 break;
    ...
}
```

Your regular expression currently matches every URI (with or without a language prefix). If this is not a requirement, remove the `?` from the regular expression. For example:

```
rewrite ^/(fr|en)/(.*)$ /$2?language=$1 break;
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for going into more detail as well, that really helps.