# Nginx URL rewrite for language parameters

Tags: regex, nginx

I have recently localized my php webpage with Gettext in a VPS running LEMP Debian 10 (PHP 7.3.27-1~deb10u1). The localized versions of the pages have the following URLs:

```
example.com/index.php?lang=es_ES
```

and

```
example.com/index.php?lang=en_GB
```

and so on.

I am trying get Nginx to rewrite the URL requests to fake folders in the following way:

`example.com/en/index.php` to=> `example.com/index.php?lang=en_GB`

`example.com/es/index.php` to=> `example.com/index.php?lang=es_ES`

and

`example.com/en/manage/index.php` to=> `example.com/manage/index.php?lang=en_EN`

`example.com/es/manage/index.php` to=> `example.com/manage/index.php?lang=es_ES`

And so on.
I have tried [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819676/nginx-rewrite-directory-language-to-query-string) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50094038/how-to-add-language-code-after-domain-name-on-nginx) with no success. My Nginx server block configuration is as follows:

```
server {

    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /(.*)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /profiles.php?user-id=$1; #pretty urls for user profiles
    }

    listen 443 ssl;
}
```

There is already a rewrite in place: `example.com/123` => `example.com/profiles.php?user-id=123`. I'd appreciate some insight on making the desired rewrites to work, without affecting the one already in place.
Thanks

Comment: In what way did those other solutions not work?

Comment: @ Sammitch the rewrites are not triggered, for example after adding the following line: `location = / {
if ($arg_lang) { return 301 /$arg_lang$uri; }
}` ,  the requests to `example.com/es_ES/index.php` return a 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
map $lang $locale {
    en      en_GB;
    es      es_ES;
}

server {

    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name example.com;

    rewrite ^/(?<lang>en|es)(?<suffix>/.*) $suffix?lang=$locale;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /(.*)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /profiles.php?user-id=$1; #pretty urls for user profiles
    }

    listen 443 ssl;
}
```

I removed `location / { try_files $uri $uri/ =404; }` because

- `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` is default nginx behavior;
- `location ~ /(.*)` will math **any** request (regex locations have greater priority than prefix ones) and will overtake any request except those ending with `.php` (regex locations are checked from first to last).

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly, thank you. @Richard's solution also worked as intended but marked your answer for the additional insight.

Answer (score 1):

Use a rewrite statement to remove the prefix and add the language argument. You probably need two rewrite statements as the language arguments are unique.

There are a number of ways to structure this, for example using separate prefix locations:

```
location ^~ /en/ {
    rewrite ^/en(/.*)$ $1?lang=en_GB last;
}
location ^~ /es/ {
    rewrite ^/es(/.*)$ $1?lang=es_ES last;
}
```